# python return dose not work saying "blabla is not defined"

Tags: python, function

So I'm studying Python and learning `def` and what it dose but when i try to run the following code

```
def test1():
    a = [" " , " " , " "]
    return a
test1()

print(a)
```

the error pop up saying that `a` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is defined only in the scope of `test1`. You have to do `a = test1()` to store the value in a.